# How do I make a rewrite rule in php?

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^(.*).htm $1.php
```

This works fine when i try to access every php page

But how could i make it `RewriteRule ^/somepage $ /somepage.php` (its not working )

if the page is about.php the url should be about/ (directory type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the rule in a .htaccess file, you need to remove the local path prefix from the pattern as it is removed before testing the pattern. In case of the root directory that is the `/`. So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage/$ /somepage.php
```

And for arbitrary path segments:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Jan's answer:

```
RewriteRule ^/about/?$ /about.php
```

will rewrite it whether they remember the final `/` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/about/$ /about.php
```

Comment: I don't think Lixon wants to add a rule for every single page.