# How do I make a rewrite rule in php?

Tags: mod-rewrite

Hey guys I'm new to mod_rewrite and just now learning how to use it. I have a question. This piece of code doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /users.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to redirect ppl that write something like www.domain.com/username to www.domain.com/users.php?username=username. Could you please help?

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is loaded and working? Did you try a simpler rule like `RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [R]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod\_rewrite Help !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506148/mod-rewrite-help)

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely an answer because @lweller is basically right. Try turning on the rewrite log and examining the output.

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

You may need to increase the log level to get the information you need.